# Scandinavian characters and file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I am loading contents from a URL; the URL is in the form www.example.com/?keyword=something. I get the specific content based on user's keyword like this:

```
$url = 'www.example.com/?';
$url = $url."keyword=$something";

function getData ($url) {

    $data = file_get_contents($url);

    return $data;
}
```

The original data contains Scandinavian characters like Ö or Å. After loading, those characters are not any more readable. How to fix this special character problem?

UPDATE:

I changed the code this way:

```
function getData ($url) {

   $data = urlencode(file_get_contents($url));
   $data = urldecode($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Didn't help either. Also  `$data = utf8_decode(urldecode($data));` and `echo utf8_decode(urldecode(getData($keyword)));` don't help. What am I doing whrong here?

Comment: May we see real url? Or it is private?

Comment: Unfortunately the uri can't be viewed to others; but it looks like this example:www.example.com/thesis_titles.jpf?studyno=43758495&passwd=HBD764UK&IDno=something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_get_contents` is not charset aware. It returns the exact bytes that it is served up. This means that if the url returns UTF-8, and you display it as iso-8859-1, then things will look wrong. Most likely, this is the case (But it could be the other way around). Either convert to ISO-8859-1, or change your app to use UTF-8. The former is possibly the simplest change - Pipe the content through `utf8_decode`, which transforms from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

E.g.:

```
function getData ($url) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = utf8_decode($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Looked like the original data was in ISO-8859-1 and I had to encode it to UTF-8, changing your solution the other way round like this: $data = utf8_encode($data); Thanks everyone for your answers and comments.

Comment: @Adia That's good, since it means that you use utf-8 as you internal charset. That isn't the default with php, but it's certainly the most sane choice, so stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the text to the proper encoding with `mb_convert_encoding`.

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($data));
```

If you are using another encoding, substitute that for `'UTF-8'`.

Answer (score 0):

use `urlencode` (before passing data via get) and `urldecode` (to decode the previously encoded string)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
and 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

PS: Files and directorys should NOT contain any umlauts or special characters!